# parse Soap XML Response using c# at child nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have below SOAP Response that i want to read the below fields:

I want to read below fields.

Status that is at:
/TrackReply/CompletedTrackDetails/TrackDetails/StatusDetail/Description

Events that is at:
/TrackReply/CompletedTrackDetails/TrackDetails/Events

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <TrackReply
        xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v18">
        <HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
        <Notifications>
            <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
            <Source>trck</Source>
            <Code>0</Code>
            <Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
            <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
        </Notifications>
        <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>Track_v18</CustomerTransactionId>
        </TransactionDetail>
        <Version>
            <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
            <Major>18</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
        </Version>
        <CompletedTrackDetails>
            <HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
            <Notifications>
                <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
                <Source>trck</Source>
                <Code>0</Code>
                <Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
                <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
            </Notifications>
            <DuplicateWaybill>false</DuplicateWaybill>
            <MoreData>false</MoreData>
            <TrackDetailsCount>0</TrackDetailsCount>
            <TrackDetails>
                <Notification>
                    <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
                    <Source>trck</Source>
                    <Code>0</Code>
                    <Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
                    <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
                </Notification>
                <TrackingNumber>395919914263</TrackingNumber>
                <TrackingNumberUniqueIdentifier>12020~395919914263~FDEG</TrackingNumberUniqueIdentifier>
                <StatusDetail>
                    <CreationTime>2020-08-24T00:00:00</CreationTime>
                    <Code>DL</Code>
                    <Description>Delivered</Description>
                    <Location>
                        <City>Potomac</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Location>
                    <AncillaryDetails>
                        <Reason>014</Reason>
                        <ReasonDescription>Left at front door.Signature Service not requested.</ReasonDescription>
                    </AncillaryDetails>
                </StatusDetail>
                <CarrierCode>FDXG</CarrierCode>
                <OperatingCompanyOrCarrierDescription>FedEx Ground</OperatingCompanyOrCarrierDescription>
                <OtherIdentifiers>
                    <PackageIdentifier>
                        <Type>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</Type>
                        <Value>A019-200818-0013</Value>
                    </PackageIdentifier>
                </OtherIdentifiers>
                <OtherIdentifiers>
                    <PackageIdentifier>
                        <Type>DEPARTMENT</Type>
                        <Value>A019-200818-0013</Value>
                    </PackageIdentifier>
                </OtherIdentifiers>
                <OtherIdentifiers>
                    <PackageIdentifier>
                        <Type>PURCHASE_ORDER</Type>
                        <Value>A019-200818-0013</Value>
                    </PackageIdentifier>
                </OtherIdentifiers>
                <Service>
                    <Type>FEDEX_GROUND</Type>
                    <Description>FedEx Ground</Description>
                    <ShortDescription>FG</ShortDescription>
                </Service>
                <PackageWeight>
                    <Units>LB</Units>
                    <Value>28.2</Value>
                </PackageWeight>
                <Packaging>
                    <Type>YOUR_PACKAGING</Type>
                    <Description>Package</Description>
                </Packaging>
                <PhysicalPackagingType>PACKAGE</PhysicalPackagingType>
                <PackageSequenceNumber>1</PackageSequenceNumber>
                <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
                <ShipmentContentPieceCount>0</ShipmentContentPieceCount>
                <PackageContentPieceCount>0</PackageContentPieceCount>
                <Payments>
                    <Classification>TRANSPORTATION</Classification>
                    <Type>SHIPPER_ACCOUNT</Type>
                    <Description>Shipper</Description>
                </Payments>
                <ShipperAddress>
                    <City>Rockville</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                    <Residential>false</Residential>
                </ShipperAddress>
                <OriginLocationAddress>
                    <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                    <Residential>false</Residential>
                </OriginLocationAddress>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>ACTUAL_DELIVERY</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2020-08-24T11:36:36-04:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>ACTUAL_PICKUP</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2020-08-21T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>SHIP</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2020-08-21T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>ACTUAL_TENDER</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2020-08-21T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>ANTICIPATED_TENDER</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2020-08-18T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DestinationAddress>
                    <City>potomac</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                    <Residential>false</Residential>
                </DestinationAddress>
                <ActualDeliveryAddress>
                    <City>Potomac</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                    <Residential>false</Residential>
                </ActualDeliveryAddress>
                <DeliveryAttempts>0</DeliveryAttempts>
                <DeliverySignatureName>Signature not required</DeliverySignatureName>
                <TotalUniqueAddressCountInConsolidation>0</TotalUniqueAddressCountInConsolidation>
                <NotificationEventsAvailable>ON_DELIVERY</NotificationEventsAvailable>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>REROUTE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>RESCHEDULE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-24T11:36:36-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>DL</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>Delivered</EventDescription>
                    <StatusExceptionCode>014</StatusExceptionCode>
                    <StatusExceptionDescription>Left at front door. Signature Service not requested.</StatusExceptionDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>Potomac</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20854</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>DELIVERY_LOCATION</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-24T09:50:00-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>OD</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>On FedEx vehicle for delivery</EventDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20879</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>VEHICLE</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-24T09:35:00-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>AR</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>At local FedEx facility</EventDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20879</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-22T05:03:00-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>AR</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>At local FedEx facility</EventDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20879</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-21T17:30:00-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>AR</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>Arrived at FedEx location</EventDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20879</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>FEDEX_FACILITY</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
                <Events>
                    <Timestamp>2020-08-21T14:53:00-04:00</Timestamp>
                    <EventType>PU</EventType>
                    <EventDescription>Picked up</EventDescription>
                    <Address>
                        <City>GAITHERSBURG</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>MD</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>20879</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Address>
                    <ArrivalLocation>PICKUP_LOCATION</ArrivalLocation>
                </Events>
            </TrackDetails>
        </CompletedTrackDetails>
    </TrackReply>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

I am able to load the XML.
Somehow I am struggling to go to these Child nodes:
Appreciate your help.

```
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
            var trackReply = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "TrackReply").FirstOrDefault();
            List<CarrierOrderStatus> lstOrderStatus = new List<CarrierOrderStatus>();
            XmlDocument configDocument = new XmlDocument();
            configDocument.LoadXml(trackReply.ToString());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement envelope = doc.Root;

            XElement xStatusDetail = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "StatusDetail").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = xStatusDetail.GetDefaultNamespace();

            StatusDetail statusDetail = new StatusDetail()
            {
                CreationTime = (DateTime)xStatusDetail.Element(ns + "CreationTime"),
                Code = (string)xStatusDetail.Element(ns + "Code"),
                Description = (string)xStatusDetail.Element(ns + "Description"),
                City = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                StateOrProvinceCode = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "StateOrProvinceCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                CountryCode = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "CountryCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                CountryName = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "CountryName").FirstOrDefault(),
                Residential = (Boolean)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "Residential").FirstOrDefault(),
                Reason = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "Reason").FirstOrDefault(),
                ReasonDescription = (string)xStatusDetail.Descendants(ns + "ReasonDescription").FirstOrDefault(),
            };

            List<XElement> xEvents   = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Events").ToList();
            ns = xEvents.FirstOrDefault().GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<Events> events = xEvents.Select(x => new Events()
            {
                Timestamp = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "Timestamp"),
                EventType = (string)x.Element(ns + "EventType"),
                EventDescription = (string)x.Element(ns + "EventDescription"),
                City = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                StateOrProvinceCode = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "StateOrProvinceCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                PostalCode = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "PostalCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                CountryCode = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "CountryCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                CountryName = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "CountryName").FirstOrDefault(),
                ArrivalLocation = (string)x.Element(ns + "ArrivalLocation"),
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class StatusDetail
    {
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateOrProvinceCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public Boolean Residential { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }

    }
    public class Events
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public string EventDescription { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateOrProvinceCode { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public Boolean Residential { get; set; }
        public string ArrivalLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```